# Autofilter not working as intended

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to delete all rows that contain a specific value in column with autofilter. For some reason, it doesn't work as intended and only deletes some of the rows with the specified value, and I'm determined to find out **WHY**

My code is as simple as this:

```
Function GetRowRange(sheet, column, value) As Range
'check for a valid section column
sheet.AutoFilterMode = False
sheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=column, Criteria1:=value
Set GetRowRange = sheet.AutoFilter.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
sheet.AutoFilterMode = False
End Function
```

```
With GetRowRange(importsheet, importsheet.UsedRange.Find("stato_4").column, "0")
    .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Delete
End With
```

**Update**
it makes no sense. I try to change my delete function to:

```
For Each Row In GetRowRange(importsheet, importsheet.UsedRange.Find("stato_4").column, "0").Offset(1, 0).Rows
    Row.EntireRow.Delete
    iront = iront + 1
Next
MsgBox iront
```

and it will recognize that there are 42 rows in the range (iront = 42), but none of them get deleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you have less than 8192 rows (pre Excel 2010), you could delete them using Special Cells?

Add a formula column that throws an error if the row contains the value you want to test for.

TRY THIS:

' Now, this formula will put an #N/A in each row where the column matches the criteria.

```
    Range("C1:C" & Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(C[-2]=criteria,NA(),"""")"
```

'Then use SpecialCells with Error code xlErrors to return the range containing the rows to be deleted.

```
    Range("C1:C" & Range("A1").end(xldown).row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas,xlErrors).entirerow.delete
```

There is more on that on [Oxgrid](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/special-cells.htm)
HTH

Philip

Comment: but I am using specialchars as far as I can see... I'm not sure I understand your reference? Thanks for the interest though

Comment: add another column with a formula in each cell: IF(Column=value,NA(), ""). Now, this formula will put an #N/A in each row where the column matches the criteria.

So you can now use SpecialCells in VBA to delete all those rows:

Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas,xlErrors).entirerow.delete

Comment: you could delete all rows like this: GetRowRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas,xlErrors).entirerow.delete ...

provided that you can put in an extra column with =NA()

Comment: Philip I'm not too confident, because actually there are 42 rows that are selected properly in my range now, but they are just not getting deleted.

Comment: since I had to use it to do some calculations, I actually chose an entirely different approach, using the standard excel functions .CountIf and .AverageIf, thereby filtering out the bad values. I couldn't get it to work the other way around, and had to be pragmatic - sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure `UsedRange` is reliable. Try using something like `Range("A1").CurrentRegion`

Comment: I need to get a variable range, that is the entire sheet range.

Comment: CurrentRegion is ideal for variable ranges !

Comment: Cool - so if i say sheet.CurrentRegion it will select all cells in the sheet?